# How do I declare a variable (val or var) holding an Array in Scala, like it would have been an ArrayList<?> in Java?

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a simple test program taken from a book that works :

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {
   val monTabEntiers = new Array[Int](30);
   val monTabEntiersInit = Array(1, 2, 5, 6);
   val monTabChaine = new Array[String](30);
   val lesSaisons = Array("été", "automne", "printemps", "hiver");

   println(monTabEntiers(0));
   println(monTabEntiersInit(0));
   println(monTabChaine(0));
   println(lesSaisons(0));

   monTabEntiersInit.update(0, 15);
   println(monTabEntiersInit(0));
...
```

But I decided to change it, because I don't like loosely typed variables.

```scala
val monTabEntiers:Array[Int] = new Array(30);
val monTabEntiersInit = Array(1, 2, 5, 6);
val monTabChaine:Array[String] = new Array(30);
val lesSaisons:Array[String] = Array("été", "automne", "printemps", "hiver");
```

But I don't know how to handle `monTabEntiersInit` to declare (even if, with its name, it's not its goal) an *Array* of anything.

How should I change this ?

```scala
val monTabEntiersInit = Array(1, 2, 5, 6);
```

I've attempted without success :

```scala
val monTabEntiersInit:Array = Array(1, 2, 5, 6);

 Refused : type parameter is asked.
```

```scala
val monTabEntiersInit:Array[_] = Array(1, 2, 5, 6);

// fails on line :
monTabEntiersInit.update(0, 15);

 found   : Int(15)
 required: _$1
```

Summarizing, I looking for a Java-like declaration of this kind (roughly written, I haven't checked the syntactic correctness below) :

```java
List<?> monTabEntiersInit = new ArrayList<?>(List.of(1, 2, 5, 6));
```

Rejecting this one :

```java
var monTabEntiersInit = new ArrayList<?>(List.of(1, 2, 5, 6));
```

Comment: Is `val monTabEntiersInit:Array[Any] = Array(1, 2, 5, 6)` ok?

Comment: Semicolons are not required in Scala

Comment: Can explain what you mean by "loosely typed variables"? I don't see any "loosely typed variables" anywhere in any of your code examples. I don't even know what that means. "Loosely typed" is not standard terminology and does not have a standard definition, everybody means something different by it. So, you will have to provide a precise, unambiguous, objective, definition of what, *exactly*, you mean by "loosely typed" if you want this question to be answerable.

Comment: To be honest, in your first example, `monTabEntiersInit` is an array of integers, but you want to change it to an array of anything. How is that "less loosely typed"? If anything, what you are attempting to do, makes things *more* loosely typed, not less.

Comment: Both using `Any` and `Arrays` are bad practices and discouraged for newcomers. Also, why sometimes you use `new` and sometimes not? All that, plus the use of semicolons, give me the impression that rather than trying to learn the language by picking a tutorial or book you are just trying to write code like this was **Java**; don't do that, please, **Scala** is more than just syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not compiles even in Java as following:

```
ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList(10);
list.set(0, "abc");
```

Instead, you should write as:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(10);
list.set(0, "abc");
```

In scala:

```
val monTabEntiersInit:Array<Any> = Array(1, 2, 5, 6)
```

Comment: Please, do not do this. Ever. You are completely throwing away type safety, and make the array essentially useless.

Answer (score 3):

The correct annotation is

```
val monTabEntiersInit: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 5, 6)
```

If you really want `monTabEntiersInit` to hold any possible value then then simple answer is to use `Any`:

```
val monTabEntiersInit: array[Any] = Array(1, 2, 5, 6)
```

However this is almost always a bad idea, and it would be better to tighten up the type. If you want to hold one of two possible types then `Either` can be used. If you need more values then consider using a trait:

```
trait Value
case class StringValue(s: String) extends Value
case class IntValue(i: Int) extends Value
case class DoubleValue(d: Double) extends Value

val monTabEntiersInit: array[Value] = ...
```

You can then use `match` to work out which value you are dealing with.

```
monTabEntiersInit(0) match {
  case StringValue(s) =>
     // process s
  case IntValue(i) =>
     // process i
  case DoubleValue(d) =>
    // process d
}
```

Comment: Declaring a new class in an existing program may ask question if it isn't yours. Strengthening a local variable you are in front of, almost never.

Comment: Using `Any` is weakening the variable, not strengthening it. The actual type is `Array[Int]` but you are forcing it to be a weaker type, `Array[Any]`.

Comment: The idea was here to allow it being an array only. What I told in my post. It's only to try the language feature. I'm not in production, here.

Answer (score 1):

First, your variables are *not* "loosely typed". Type annotations are optional in scala, but it is still strictly typed.

```
val monTabEntiersInit = Array(1, 2, 5, 6) // you don't need semi-colons
```

declares an array of `Int`, which is *a lot less* "loosely typed" than `Array[Any]` you end up with. The latter is way too loose, and should almost always be avoided: using `Any` completely circumvents the type system and makes the collection largely unusable.

Finally, your problem is not with the type declaration so much as with mutating variables in place. It is highly unusual and frowned upon in scala, and just not a "scala way". You should avoid that.
Note, that while

```
   val foo: Array[_] = Array(1,2,3)
   foo.update(0,0)
```

does not work, something like this:

```
   val x = Array(1,2,3)
   val y = x.updated(0,0) // Still Array[Int]
   val z = x.updated(1, "one") // Now Array[Any]
```

not only works, and is thread safe and referentially transparent, but also keeps track of the resulting array properly.

In general, outside from a few highly specialized cases where you are looking to optimize the last few milliseconds of performance, do not use `Array`, use `Seq`/`List` (for sequential collection), `LazyList`/`Iterator` (for streaming, and/or iterate-once semantics), `IndexedSeq`/`Vector` (for random access). And don't mutate things ni place. That's just ... bad.

To summarize, a few "rules of thumb" that are almost universal in scala:

- Do not use `Any`
- Do not mix object types in the same collection
- Do not mutate things in place and avoid mutable structures (like `Array`)
- Do rely on scala type inference wherever possible and avoid type annotations that relax type constraints without reason.

Comment: `val z = x.updated(1, "one") // Now Array[Any]` is exactly the situation I would like to avoid, and why I am searching to constraint the variables themselves the sooner I can.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I know :) But _why_ are you trying to "avoid" it? It is a _good_ situation. At least, definitely much better than what you end up with. Using `Any` does not `constrain` anything, opposite of that. Mutating an existing array with a value of unknown type, is _even worse_.